# Can you share $_SESSION cookies between domains with setcookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to create a SSO login with `setcookie` and `$_SESSION`. I know that you can create a cookie on another domain with `setcookie`. Can I do the same with `$_SESSION`?

This is how it would work. The user goes to the login domain -> they login -> server sets `$_SESSION` cookie(s) on master domain/other domain (depends). Is there anyway I can do this? I don't want to do

```
setcookie('$_SESSION', $_SESSION, time() + 3600, '/', '.testsite.com');
```

because it puts actual text the people can edit easily with chrome extensions and get into other people's accounts as I am implementing apps.
Can I do this?

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', $_SESSION, time() + 3600, '/', '.testsite.com');
```

Comment: i will suggest using db session (saving you sessions on db instead of file) this easier to implement in laravel framework

Comment: How can I do this and do this (within like SSO(single sign on) and use setcookie?)

Answer (score 0):

DB sessions is not really good idea because you cannot check SESSIONS everytime by querying DB, too much expensive operations and chances are that your DB will always be full. I implemented SSO in one of my projects using this architecture. It is fairly simple and easy to understand. You can implement SSO using iframes and having a SSO domain.
https://yoyodesign.com/thoughts/knowledge/2013/may/single-sign-on-a-proof-of-concept/